# Почему std::memcmp работает медленнее обычного цикла?

Tags: c++, производительность, c++14

Доброго времени суток. Проводя рефакторинг заметил что при сравнении двух массивов заменив обычный цикл на std::memcmp код стал работать медленнее. Написал небольшой тест и действительно, если сравнивать два массива размерность 10, обычный цикл работает примерно в 3 раза быстрее, что до оптимизации что после. Пробовал на компиляторе MVS и на GCC. Это нормально, или я что-то упустил? Есть ли что-то побыстрее  std::memcmp для сравнения коротких массивов у которых нет итераторов?

Ниже представлен код. Сравнивал вставляя точки останова на местах создания L…(знаю что так сравнивать производительность не совсем корректно, но для сравнения порядка производительности этого достаточно).

```
char ArrayA[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
char ArrayB[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
bool c = true;
volatile int* L1 = new int; // Точка замера времени
for (int i = 0; i < 100'000'000; i++) {
    ArrayB[5] = static_cast<char>(i);
    c = std::memcmp(ArrayA, ArrayB, sizeof(ArrayB));
}
volatile int* L2 = new int; // Точка замера времени
std::cout << c << std::endl;
volatile int* L3 = new int; // Точка замера времени
for (int i = 0; i < 100'000'000; i++) {
    c = false; // Если массивы равны, возвращаем false как memcmp
    ArrayB[5] = static_cast<char>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(ArrayB); j++) {
        if (ArrayA[j] != ArrayB[j]) {
            c = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
volatile int* L4 = new int; // Точка замера времени
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

Comment: В коде, который вы рефакторите, также как и в коде вопроса содержимое массивов известно во время компиляции и модифицируется элементов с индексом 5, что также известно  компилятору?

Comment: Известен размер только первого массива и он константнен. Второй массив это кусок большого массива который приходит по сети. Сразу скажу что это не задача поиска подстроки в строке.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слишком простой код, для того, чтобы заставить компилятор генерировать честный цикл во второй части.

В вашем исходном варианте компилятор GCC в режиме `-O3` предсказывает правильный ответ для второй части кода еще на стадии компиляции. То есть никакого сравнения не делается вообще.

Даже если усложнить задачу и сделать

```
ArrayB[5] = rand();
```

анализ сгенерированного кода все равно показывает, что компилятор GCC прекрасно видит, что `ArrayA[j]` будет равно `ArrayB[j]` для любых значений `j`, кроме `5`. Поэтому никакого цикла во второй части кода не делается вообще - делается сравнение только `ArrayA[5] != ArrayB[5]`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы компилятор честно сравнивал все, то делайте

```
ArrayB[rand() % 10] = rand();
```

но даже и в этом случае компилятор полностью развернет второй цикл.

Чтобы сравнение с `memcmp` было более честным и осмысленным, надо чтобы 1) размер сравнения не был известен на стадии компиляции, 2) размер сравнения был достаточно большим, чтобы предотвратить полную развертку цикла. Сделайте количество сравниваемых элементов равным `1 + rand() % 100` и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: "В вашем исходном варианте компилятор GCC в режиме -O3" Я пробовал со всеми уровнями оптимизации.

Comment: AnT спасибо за ответ и что разжевали).

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, вы не измеряете, а оцениваете на глаз в лучшем случае...

Проведем эксперимент:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory.h>

using namespace std;

class muTimer
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    bool active = false;
    Clock::duration   duration_;
    Clock::time_point start_ = Clock::now(), stop_ = Clock::now();

    muTimer(const muTimer&)             = delete;
    muTimer& operator=(const muTimer&)  = delete;
public:
    using ns       = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using mks      = std::chrono::microseconds;
    using ms       = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    muTimer() { reset(); start(); }
    ~muTimer() = default;
    muTimer& reset()
    {
        duration_ = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
        active    = false;
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& start()
    {
        if (!active)
        {
            start_ = Clock::now();
            active = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& stop()
    {
        if (active)
        {
            stop_      = Clock::now();
            duration_ += stop_ - start_;
            active     = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename T = mks>
        unsigned long long duration()
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned long long>
            (std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(stop_-start_).count());
    }
};


const int COUNT = 10000;
const int TRIES = 10000;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    volatile char * a = new char[COUNT];
    volatile char * b = new char[COUNT];
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        a[i] = b[i] = rand() % 255;

    {
        int total = 0;
        muTimer mu;
        mu.start();
        for(int i = 0; i < TRIES; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < COUNT; ++j)
                if (a[j] != b[j]) { ++total; break; }
        }
        cout << total << "  " << mu.stop().duration() << endl;
    }
    {
        int total = 0;
        muTimer mu;
        mu.start();
        for(int i = 0; i < TRIES; ++i)
        {
            if (memcmp((void*)a,(void*)b,COUNT)) ++total;
        }
        cout << total << "  " << mu.stop().duration() << endl;
    }
}
```

Результат при компиляции VC++ 2017 на моей машине - примерно 51ms против 4ms для `memcmp`.

Результат для GCC - смотрите сами: https://ideone.com/EYg3X9

P.S. добавление по совету AnT

```
int total = 0;
srand(123);
muTimer mu;
...
for(int j = 0; j < rand()%COUNT; ++j)  // memcmp((void*)a,(void*)b,rand()%COUNT)
```

картину никак не меняет.

P.P.S. Добавил примерно как в вопросе изменение массива `b` - только в самый конец:

```
    b[COUNT - 100 + i%100] = (char)i;
```

Тоже принципиально ничего не изменило.

**Update**

При работе с малыми массивами использование вызываемой библиотечной функции дает слишком большие накладные расходы - тот же `call memcmp` приводит к сбросу кэша предвыборки команд, что и приводит к тому, что **на небольших** массивах `memcmp` оказывается узким местом.

Comment: Harry спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Внимательно разобрал ваш тест. Он у вас не совсем корректен из-за участка a[i] = b[i] = rand() % 255; т.е. У вас массивы всегда будут равны, что наихудший случай для варианта с циклами. Если переписать этот участок что у а и b будут свои вызовы rand() и увеличить количество траев, то вариант с циклами снова выигрывает.

Comment: Я специально задавал так, чтобы работали на длинных массивах. Проверять на коротком - особенно таком, как у вас - тут я результатам бы не верил за счет того, что накладные расходы могут перевесить саму работу кода. Тогда надо четко ограничивать условия - работаем с очень короткими массивами или еще что. Понимаете, на коротком массиве сам вызов через `call` со сбросом кэша предвыборки команд (или как он там правильно называется), будет бешеным тормозом.

Comment: Я понимаю что на сам вызов функции тратятся ресурсы, но я эти границы обозначил с самого начала в вопросе, "если сравнивать два массива размерность 10". Может я выразился не совсем точно. Меня интересует целесообразность использования std::memcmp на участках где сравнения коротких массивов производится очень часто O(n^2) или O(n^3).

Comment: Увы, но, по-моему, кроме самых тривиальных случаев (типа использовать быструю сортировку или сортировку вставками для больших массивов :)) априори сказать что-то очень сложно. Это тот случай, когда интуиция - очень ненадежная вещь, и нужно просто на конкретных данных, машине и компиляторе сравнивать разные варианты...  Кстати, очень рекомендую [эту книжку](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-6-7.html)...

Comment: Harry спасибо вам еще раз. Обязательно прочту.

Comment: Правильное замечание от @mrFieldy. Эксперимент совершенно нерепрезентативный и не имеет отношения к эксперименту в исходном вопросе. В этом варианте компилятор вообще устраняет цикл по `TRIES` для `memcmp` варианта, ибо знает семантику `memcmp`. В коде автора вопроса специально сделана модификация массива между сравнениями, чтобы исключить такую оптимизацию. Здесь этой модификации нет, по каковой причине этот код получится совсем другим, не имеющим отношения к исходному.

Comment: Также в коде дополнительно содержится ярко выраженный "читинг" - массивы видны через указатель как `volatile` (!). Это подавляет оптимизации для варианта с явным циклом. А для `memcmp` это `volatile` насильно устраняется при помощи явного каста к `(void *)`. Это уж совсем белиберда какая-то получается! Для того, чтобы эти тесты имели какой-то смысл, ни о каком `volatile` не может быть и речи. `volatile` убираем, добавляем `a[rand() % COUNT] = rand();` между сравнениями, и сразу же видим, что вариант с циклом - быстрее, чем `memcmp`.

Comment: Ну почему всегда, когда я провожу какой-то эксперимент - естественно, с какими-то огрехами и т.д. - то критики никогда не проводят свой, а ограничиваются только критикой? :) Так и вспоминается - "не можешь сам - учи других"...

Comment: @AnT И, кстати, убрать `volatile` - опять же ничего не меняет по сути, как и добавление вашего rand() - убедитесь сами. вместо `COUNT/2 + rand()%(COUNT/2)` используете просто `rand()%COUNT` - получите практически одинаковое время - за счет того, что вы делаете массивы **короткими**, чтобы играли роль накладные расходы на `call` (забавно, что в своем ответе при этом пишете - чтобы сравнение было честным, размер сравнения должен быть большим...) https://ideone.com/4zBdDR Теоретизируйте дальше, что еще у меня не так и как бы изменить, чтоб было, как вам хочется? :)

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю этого комментария. Во-первых, вопрос автора уже содержит эксперимент и фактически является вопросом по этому эксперименту. Какой смысл предлагать другой эксперимент, если он не соответствует исходному практически никак? (Это уже не говоря о том, что ответы типа "Да выкинь ты свой код нафиг. Смотри, как надо" - не приветствуются). Во-вторых, эксперименты над производительностью кода на ideone - без возможности управления настройками компилятора - это бессмыслица по определению. Там действительно можно не увидеть влияния ничего.

Comment: Harry, если в Вашем сравнении в цикле сравнивать не по одному char`у -->  if (a[j] != b[j]), а сравнивать к приведенном указателю на unsigned long long*, то можно сократить время на порядок  и почти приблизится к memcmp, а не больших сравниваемых массивах и обогнать.